# How do I replace specific numbers/letters of a text file using batch?

Tags: batch-file

Imagine the following numbers make up a text file called "dog.txt".

116267
831256
876825
687123

How could I change only a select few of these letters using batch code? For example, if I wanted to only change the "2" to a "U" on the top row, how could I select that specific number and change it? The numbers are purely placeholders, they don't mean anything except the position they're in- I'd want to have them selected like a chess board, where it goes from A-H, 1-8, not just selecting all the twos and turning them into U's.

TL;DR: Turn that into this

116U67
831256
876825
687123

Comment: You have not specified enough information about your algorithm. Also, this will be a lot simpler in PowerShell than in cmd.exe shell script (batch).

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q42982193.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"


(
SET /a col=%2+1
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r "." "%filename1%"') DO (
 IF %%a equ %1 (
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  SET "line=:%%b"
  SET "line=!line:~0,%2!%3!line:~%col%!"
  ECHO !line:~1!
  ENDLOCAL 
 ) ELSE ECHO %%b
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q42982193.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Given parameters *row column replacementchar* then simply read the file and number each line using `findstr` then assign the row# to `%%a` and the line contents to `%%b`.

If the row number doesn't match the required number in the parameter list, regurgitate the line.

If it matches, prefix it with a colon (or any other character) so that the string-start becomes 1-based, then select the appropriate sections of the line, string them with the replacement character and output the result, removing the first character.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really confused on how to do this.